# Sqlite_master not updating

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I have a function that should return true if a table exists in a file (test.db). For a time this was working fine but I recently deleted the .db file to test that the rest of the code would be able to generate the database from scratch. However, instead of the function returning false, it continues to return true even though the table definitely does not exist.

The code:

```
public static boolean tableExists(String table){
boolean tableExists = true;
try{
    sql = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name ='"+table+"' and type='table'; ";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    }catch(Exception e){
        tableExists = false;
    }
return tableExists;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about sqlite api, but `SELECT` does not look like an "update" to me.

Comment: I'm not trying to update sqlite_master from within the function but I don't know whether sqlite_master is cached somewhere and needs to be manually updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function does not actually check whether the query returns data or not.
(And `executeUpdate` does not make sense for SELECT statements.)

You have to try to read what the query returns:

```
public static boolean tableExists(String table) {
    sql = "SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master WHERE name ='"+table+"' and type='table'";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    return rs.first();
}
```